# Ruby flow control: throw an exception, return nil or let it fail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, control-flow

I am thinking of the best practices of flow control. Which way should I go?

1) Don't check anything and let the program fail (cleaner code, natural error messages):

```
  def self.fetch(feed_id)
    feed = Feed.find(feed_id)
    feed.fetch
  end
```

2) Fail silently by returning nil (however, "Clean Code" says, that you should never return null):

```
  def self.fetch(feed_id)
    return unless feed_id
    feed = Feed.find(feed_id)
    return unless feed
    feed.fetch
  end
```

3) Throw exceptions (because it's exceptional not to find a feed by id):

```
  def self.fetch(feed_id)
    raise ArgumentError.new unless feed_id
    feed = Feed.find(feed_id)
    raise ArgumentError.new unless feed
    feed.fetch
  end
```

To put it in other words: should I be using guard conditions actively, or is it better to rely on Ruby / Rails methods and let them throw an exception, if something wrong happens?

Comment: if this ActiveRecord, a `find` will blow if the `id` does not exist, `find_by_id` does not blow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1) Don't check anything and let the program fail (cleaner code,
>   natural error messages):

It's ok to "let the program fail" with known, documented exceptions, but getting an unpleasant `NoMethodError` because you tried to use a `nil` object is just careless. In your particular example, `ActiveRecord#find` raises a documented `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception, so IMO this is the way to go:

```
def self.fetch(feed_id)
  Feed.find(feed_id).fetch
end
```

> 2) Fail silently by returning nil (however, "Clean Code" says, that
>   you should never return null):

That's fine as a general advice, but Ruby is crammed with methods that return `nil`; and that's ok (again, as long as it's documented), it just means "Nothing" (and allows the very compact pattern `something_that_can_be_nil || another_value`). In this case I'd write it concisely using Ick's `maybe`:

```
def self.fetch(feed_id)
  Feed.find_by_id(feed_id).maybe.fetch
end
```

> 3) Throw exceptions (because it's exceptional not to find a feed by
>   id):

Yes, but then let the method raise the well-known `RecordNotFound` exception, not a custom one (unless you want to abstract the fact that you are working with AR, which can be very cumbersome).

Answer (score 2):

I think the right answer is: it depends. The user theoratically should never encounter any error message from the framework. You must always be prepared to handle these exceptions. The choice is all yours (if it is not an externally used interface or something).

If you take the first route, I think you should fist query that is any feed exist with that id, and then try to fetch it. If the feed disappears between the two, that can be a real problem to report. The third is basically the same. You need to make sure, that you handled every situation, and in that throwing exception can help to prevent the user seeing the error.

The second solution is basically this, but with an internal handling. With the nil you signal that there is some problem. It also must be handled, reported to the user, or something. The drawback is if you forget this, you may mislead the user.

I would use the first method, with an extra check before to make sure it exists. But it depends on the usage.

Comment: Yes it depends. If it is a fatal error that the operation must be successful to keep the program going on, let it fail or throw an exception. Otherwise just return nil

Answer (score 2):

I would go for the clean version.

If you don't supply a `feed_id` to the `fetch` method, ruby itself will raise `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments(0 for 1)`, so the first part of #3 is pointless.

If you don't supply a valid `feed_id`, then the `Feed.find(feed_id)` call will raise a different exception, most likely `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` with a message either saying that it could not find a feed with the supplied ID, or if no ID was supplied (the `feed_id` parameter was `nil`), that it could not find a feed without an ID.

To me it seems kind of stupid to call the method with `feed_id = nil`, so I would probably argue that "if you send invalid input, it might break", and in that case, I think that the `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` will give you much more information about what went wrong than if you raise an `ArgumentError`.

Returning a null value is seldom a good thing, since that won't tell you what actually went wrong. Therefore, I would also rule out #2.